# Wordpress setup_postdata not returning any content

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress as headless CMS.

I use the following function to return a page based on the page title.

No code or Wordpress content has changed and *suddenly* it has stopped working...

Almost indentical code on the same server on a different site is working fine.

Anyone got any ideas what might have happened ?

```
// -- Get page based on page name -- //
    function getWordpressPage($wordpressPageName){
        $page = NULL;
        $pageRequest = cleanUrlVar($wordpressPageName);
        if($pageRequest){
            $page = get_page_by_title( $pageRequest );
            if($page != NULL){
                setup_postdata($page);
                return the_content();
            }
        }
        if($page == ''){
            header('Location: /');
            exit();
        }
    }
```

FYI - var_dump($page) returns the data so Wordpress is returning something, it looks like it's falling over at the 'return the_content() stage...

Answer (score 0):

`the_content()` will show the content by echo it. So if you want to get
variable to return, you should use `get_the_content()`

Update your codes to return it:

```
return get_the_content();
```

You can find out more here:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/

Comment: Probably wouldn't even need `setup_postdata` any more then (rather costly operation, I presume?), since this one takes the post ID as third parameter, so leaving the first & second at their defaults, this could be `return get_the_content( null, false, $page );` here, and the call to `setup_postdata` be removed.

Comment: Tried all combinations of that - nothing is working :(

Comment: @PatDobson Could you print_r($page) and make a screen shot on it? I want to check the data.